# Minishift: oc 3.11 cannot login, error: couldn't get htttps//<ip>:443/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server: unexpected response status 503

Tags: minishift

After a restart, `oc login $(minishift ip) -u system:admin` does not work. Error is:

```
The server is using a certificate that does not match its hostname: x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.42.207 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
You can bypass the certificate check, but any data you send to the server could be intercepted by others.
Use insecure connections? (y/n): y

error: couldn't get https://192.168.42.207:443/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server: unexpected response status 503
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that `https://192.168.42.207:8443/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server` respond with content, so I change it to be 8443 and login works.

```
oc login $(minishift ip):8443 -u system:admin
```

I didn't have to use official documentation way to get another `oc` client. I am using 3.11.